# Installing phonegap 3.x WITHOUT using NPM

Tags: cordova

Is there a way to install phonegap 3.x WITHOUT using NPM? The phonegap install page ([Phonegap install link](http://phonegap.com/install/)) offers archive packages for versions leading up to 2.9.1. I can't find any stand-alone packages for anything greater than 2.9.1. I have a need to have several different versions of phonegap on the same machine, and NPM doesn't seem to allow that.

Comment: You could install cordova from zip (see download folder in apache cordova site) but then installing plugins would be a pain. Rajesh's answer seems better.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a need to have several different versions of phonegap on the same machine, and NPM doesn't seem to allow that.

Read [`npm-install`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/install.html) documentation.

`npm install <name>@<version>` is what you need.

You can install multiple versions on the same machine, but only one of them will be active at any given time. You can, of course, switch between the versions at any time.

Comment: do you understand how the phonegap npm versioning works? If I run a `npm view phonegap version` I can see multiple versions of every semantically versioned release, like so:
`'2.8.0-0.10.0',
  '2.8.0-0.10.1',
  '2.8.0-0.10.2',
  '2.8.0-0.10.3',
  '2.8.0-0.10.4',
  '2.8.0-0.10.6',` 
The reason I was going after those archives is mostly because their npm versioning is a bit confusing and I can't find anything to explain it anywhere.

Comment: Please take a look at the [`phonegap-cli`](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli) on GitHub. TL;DR - only the `2.8.0` is the one of interest to apps.

Comment: If I try to use npm to install 2.8.0 like this - npm install -g phonegap@2.8.0 - then I get an error from npm saying version not found. This is because there is no "2.8.0" version - only the versions of 2.8.0 that I listed above. How do I know which one to use?

Comment: Have you tried `npm install -g phonegap@2.8`, `npm install -g phonegap@2.9`, etc.?

Comment: I just tried it and while it did work, it installed `2.8.1-0.11.0`. I do actually need to target 2.8.0 specifically for some plugin compatibility. Strange but now when I do an `npm view phonegap version` all I see is `3.4.0-0.19.13` when before I saw a lot of versions. These guys really need to get their shit together! :)